# Tag synonym rsyslogd -> rsyslog

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Just wanted to propose a tag synonym from `rsyslogd` to `rsyslog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve [created the synonym suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/rsyslog/synonyms).